# Search a string containing number recursively by loop through different files and replace the number to another number using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to replace DEACTIVATE IS = 0 with DEACTIVATE IS = 2 by looping through different files and subfolders within C:\Test folder. I am using the below code but I am not getting the expected results. From this code DEACTIVATE IS = 0 is getting replaced with 0=DEACTIVATE IS = 2= 0.

Kindly help me out.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "search=DEACTIVATE IS = 0"
set "replace=DEACTIVATE IS = 2"

for /R "C:\Test" %%j in (*) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        >>"%%~j" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
```

This is what I have tried, however I am getting result as DEACTIVATE IS = 0 getting replaced with 0=DEACTIVATE IS = 2= 0 from above code.

Expected Result is DEACTIVATE IS = 0 to be replaced with DEACTIVATE IS = 2.

Kindly help out.

Comment: The problem is thst you have strings which contsin tje `=` character, which is a special character in the string replacement. Would it not therefore make more sense to locate lines which contain the entire string sequence, `DEACTIVATE IS = 0`, (using find.exe or findstr.exe), and if it matches, just `>>"%%~j" echo(DEACTIVATE IS = 2`, instead of trying to perform an expansion and replacement.

Comment: Just a hint, you might get less headaches by starting to use powershell...